# How does one pull a value from within a tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple of tuples in my code called "translations" that contains conversions of letters to numbers e.g. ("A", "1") is one of the tuples. From this tuple of tuples I need to call a value based on what the user inputs (e.g. if they enter A,B,C the code replies with 1,2,3 from the tuple).

```
messageToConvert = str(input('Enter letters to convert: '))
 for numbers in messageToConvert:
     characters_to_decode = messageToConvert.split(',')
 coded_text = []
 for i in characters_to_decode:
     coded_text.append(translations[i])
```

When i try to run it I keep getting the error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str " because of the [i] after translations being a variable. I want to program to check all of the characters entered that are separated by commas, convert them to numbers, and then output them as a string.

Comment: Given the last sentence, it might also be worth looking into the builtin functions [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and possibly (its inverse) [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr).  (e.g. `print(ord("J") - ord("A") + 1)` results in "10", as "J" is the 10th letter of the alphabet).

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate data structure to use if you want to use one value to look up another is a dictionary. Conveniently, you can create a dictionary using a list of tuples:

```py
>>> tuples = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)]
>>> dictionary = dict(tuples)
>>> dictionary["B"]
2
```

You only need to build the dictionary once, even if you will need to do many lookups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I shall try that out!